# How to determine if a polynomial is a subspace of $R_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$$W = \{ (x-1)p(x) \mid \ p(x) \ \in \ R_2, p(-1) = 0\}$$

How do I check if $W$ is a subspace of $R_3$ without using matrices? I know that $W$ has to be closed under addition and scalar multiplication, but I don't know how to prove or show it properly. Also, how to find the basis of $W$?

Thanks.

Comment: To show closed under addition.  Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two elements of your set.  Then check whether $\alpha+\beta$ is an element of the set.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant that I know the steps in solving these questions, it's just that I have no idea how to prove $(x-1)p(x)$ is closed under addition and scalar addition.

Comment: What does $R_2$ denote in this context? Is it the set of polynomials with real coefficient and degree 2 or less?

Comment: @user202729 Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha, \beta \in W$, then $\alpha = (x-1)p(x) $ & $ \beta=(x-1)q(x)$ for some $p,q\in R_2$ with $p(-1)=0$ & $q(-1)=0$.

Now $\alpha +\beta =(x-1)(p(x)+q(x))=(x-1)(p+q)(x)$ and also $p+q\in R_2$, so only you need to check whether $(p+q)(-1)=0$.

For basis of $W$, first find basis of $\{p\in R_2\mid p(-1)=0\}$